# How to divide each values of the group with total size in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with Yes/no answer in the column 'quality','price','time'.

I transformed in 1 and 0 and grouped

`grouped = df.group.by(['country'])[['quality','price','time']].sum()` to get only the 'Yes' answers and the result is:

| country | quality | price | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FRANCE | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| GERMANY | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| UK | 2 | 1 | 4 |

I would like to know how to divide each values in groupby for the size(N total) of each country respondents, in my case FRANCE = 9 , GERMANY = 11, UK = 12.

I know that i can select single group and make operations with it:
`france = country_split.loc[['FRANCE']]`

`(france/9)*100`

but it is  possible to make operations for the entire group in one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counts and divide values of columns after aggregate `sum`, then multiple by `100`:

```
#if need dict for counts
#s = {'FRANCE': 9, 'GERMANY': 11, 'UK': 12}

s = df['country'].value_counts()

grouped = df.groupby(['country'])[['quality','price','time']].sum().div(s, axis=0).mul(100)
print (grouped)
           quality      price       time
country                                 
FRANCE   55.555556  44.444444  33.333333
GERMANY  27.272727  18.181818  54.545455
UK       16.666667   8.333333  33.333333
```

Not tested, but possible solution should be aggregate `mean` instead `sum`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['country'])[['quality','price','time']].mean()
```